# как стереть то что нарисовано в Bitmap

Tags: android

Есть ли какой-то метод для очистки изображения в Bitmap изображение нарисовано при помощи Canvas? Заливка сплошным цветом не подходит.
вообщем задача такая - для рисования Path пальцем мне не нужно очищать экран, а вот когда рисую окружность (при движении пальца меняется радиус) мне необходимо ее перерисовывать. если заливать цветом стирается предыдущий рисунок

Comment: @Kromster для рисования Path пальцем мне не нужно очищать экран, а вот когда рисую окружность (при движении пальца меняется радиус) мне необходимо ее перерисовывать. если заливать цветом стирается предыдущий рисунок

Comment: я вижу такой способ - "рисовать" на отдельном слое, и если нужно стереть, то удалять его. Если же рисовать на том же самом битмапе, где уже есть рисунок, то придется запоминать, что было под линией.

Comment: @Эникейщик а как потом добавить рисунок на основной слой?

Comment: ну очевидно скопировать значения нарисованных пикселей

Comment: @Эникейщик вы наверное не поняли задачу. Я делаю программу для рисования типа Paint мне нужно рисовать всевозможные фигуры и произвольное рисование. Для произвольного рисования очистка Bitmap не нужна, а вот для фигур необходима чтобы не отрисовывались предыдущие размеры. Я не пойму как и где удалять Bitmap ведь он мне нужен на следующей отрисовке экрана

Comment: Я понял задачу. Вам знакома концепция слоев в графических редакторах? Нигде не было речи про удаление вашего битмапа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144631/discussion-between---and-).